# Can you get the Guardin' Gnome achievement on Easy difficulty?

Tags: left-4-dead-2

If you complete the Dark Carnival campaign, and take the gnome all the way to the helicopter, on easy difficulty, do you still get the achievement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Xbox 360, you definitely do, yes. I can't see why the PC version would be different.

Comment: Yes, it worked. I was able to get it on that setting. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can do it on any difficulty, whatever the support (PC/Xbox).

Since it isn't especially an easy one, if you just want to get the achiev', you'll probably prefer to get it on easy.  But it's also a great challenge to try it on expert.

Comment: Yes, I tried doing it on Expert at first, for almost 3 days. Gave up and went to normal. Tried again for another 2-3 days, but ended up getting into not so experienced teams, and having weird issues (bad luck on spawns, strange servers, and so forth).  So I gave up and did it on easy on the first try. Thanks!

Comment: I highly recommend to try it with friends: it can quickly get hilarious ! ;)